# Troubles with scrolling the mobile version of website on apple products (the scroll is super fast), however on android everything works perfectly

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, css

I have noticed, when I open mobile version of my website on android, scroll is perfect

[image: scroll on android samsung]

**however**, when I open the website on **iphone**, the scroll breaks and it gets **unconctrollably fast**

[image: scroll on iphone]

I also noticed that when opening on iphone, the code changes: there is new `<div>` and also body gets `class="scroll_wrapper"` even if these are not in the html file.

```html
<body class="scroll_wrapper">
<noindex></noindex> 
<div id="webit_scroll_provider_wrapper" class="html" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; width: 100%; min-width: 480px;">
```

I have no idea what is wrong. Please help! In CSS file the .scroll wrapper is

```css
.scroll_wrapper
{
 position: absolute;
 overflow: auto;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: If you need here is the link to the mobile version of the website: http://iwatch.itimpi.kz/phone

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some sort of javascript running as I can see an inline style applying `top: -3928px; left: 0px` in your animation on iPhone 6, but not on the Galaxy.
Look for anything that runs on the window scroll event as that will be your problem.